# prove or disprove: If $f(x)$ is defined in $[a,b]$, then its bounded.

Tags: calculus

prove or disprove: If $f(x)$ is defined in $[a,b]$, then it's bounded.

pretty sure i need to disprove this because if it was true, there was no need for weierstrass.

Comment: You need continuity, and in this case, it is Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: yes i know, that is why i need to disprove this.

Comment: @ajotatxe continuity is a sufficient but not necessary condition

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Try a discontinuous function.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. Just take$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x=a\\\dfrac1{x-a}&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: 1/x is not enough if f(0)=0?

Comment: @YanivPerry I don't even know if $0\in[a,b]$ or not. Therefore, I cannot answer your question.

Comment: lets say [a,b]=[0,1]
can i say that f(x)=1/x,
f(0)=0?

Comment: @YanivPerry Of course. If $a=0$ and $b=1$, that's the same function that I described, right?! Did you think that I would say now that that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Define
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\min\{n\in\Bbb N:nx\in\Bbb Z\}\text{ if }x\in\Bbb Q\\0\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

It is not the simplest counterexample, but it is a good exercise to prove that it is not bounded.